# How to send session in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send session's data in blade. before logout, I create a session. created session's data send in blade.how I can do this.

```
public function userLogout()
{
    if (!empty(session("userLoggedIn")) && session("userLoggedIn") == true) {
        $session = session()->get('userDetails');
        $user_id = $session->id;
        $user_package = UserPackage::all()->where('user_id','=',$user_id);
        foreach($user_package as $package_id) {
            $package_detail = Package::where('id','=',$package_id->package_id)->get();
            foreach( $package_detail as $package ){
                $package_amount = $package->price;
                $package_tagline = $package->tagline;
            }
        }
        session()->flush();
        session()->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('frontend-home')->with('session', session()->put('package_detail',[$package_tagline,$package_amount]));
}
```

after I try this result is nothing.And how to session's data print inn blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. If you have already set the session you dont need to carry to another page it can be available throughout the project.

You can access like this in blade:

```
<div>
    {{ Session::get('package_detail') }}
</div>
```

2. You can do like this in blade file:

   ```
    @foreach($package_detail as $product)
        {{ $product['title'] }}
    @endforeach
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function userLogout()
{
    if ($request->session()->has("userLoggedIn")) { // has returns true for userLoggedIn is true and not null 
        $session = session()->get('userDetails');
        $user_id = $session->id;
        $user_package = UserPackage::all()->where('user_id','=',$user_id);
        foreach($user_package as $package_id) {
            $package_detail = Package::where('id','=',$package_id->package_id)->get();
            foreach( $package_detail as $package ){
                $package_amount[] = $package->price;
                $package_tagline[] = $package->tagline;
            }
        }
        session()->flush();
        session()->save();
    }
    $package_detail['package_amount'] = $package_amount;
    $package_detail['package_tagline'] = $package_tagline;
    $packageCollection = collect($package_detail);
    return redirect()->route('frontend-home')->put('package_detail',$packageCollection);
}
```

access the blade like this

```
@foreach (Session::get('package_detail') as $product_id)
    {{$product_id}}
 @endforeach
```